# Looking for a less confusing way to accomplish array switching - swift

Tags: swift

This is my current setup

```
struct Zot {}

class Foo {
    // When changed, this will reset the active array
    var activeArrayIndex: Int = -1 {
        didSet {
            activeArray = arrays[activeArrayIndex]
        }
    }
    // When changed, ensure that the changes are reflected in the arrays variable
    var activeArray: [Zot] = [] {
        didSet {
            arrays[activeArrayIndex] = activeArray
        }
    }
    var arrays: [[Zot]] = []

    // Pass in array of Zots
    init(zotArrays: [Zot]) {
        // Iterate through each one and set each as index zero in their own arrays
        for zot in zotArrays {
            let newArray: [Zot] = [zot]
            // Append to array of arrays.
            self.arrays.append(newArray)
        }
        // If empty, leave single empty array
        if arrays.isEmpty {
            self.arrays.append([])
        }
        // Set index to 0 to update active array
        self.activeArrayIndex = 0
    }
}
```

I have 5 buttons. Tapping one of these buttons will set the activeArrayIndex based on which button was tapped.

This whole thing works which is great, but it feels clunky. Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you really need the activeArray property, to me it looks like you could access the arrays property directly using the index property without having to store the result?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson or have a computed property with `get` and `set`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I suppose that's true. I was struggling to think through what I was doing yesterday and had settled on an approach I knew was suboptimal, but couldn't figure out the better approach. I will drop the activeArray property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation also has a bug because, if you retrieve `activeArray` before you set it, you will always get an empty array.

You should either just use the index directly into the backing array as Joakim suggests in the  comments, or use a computed property.

```
var activeArray: [Zot]
{
    get { arrays[activeArrayIndex] }
    set { arrays[activeArrayIndex] = newValue }
}
```

You might want to be careful with this latter approach in case the whole array is copied when you only want to set one element. For example

```
    foo.activeArray[x] = someZot
```

might cause copying of the whole array. The alternative

```
    foo.arrays[activeArrayIndex][x] = someZot
```

is almost as reasonable.

Your `init` is a bit confusing. It seems to me you want t take an array of `Zot` and transform it into an array of one element `Zot`s. You can do this in one line.

```
    init(zotArrays: [Zot])
    {
        self.arrays = zotArrays.isEmpty ? [[]] : zotArrays.map { [$0] }
        self.activeArrayIndex = 0
    }
```

OK, two lines

**Update**

I've just discovered a new feature ofSwift which is designed for this exact situation. My example above *does* result in unnecessary copies, but since Swift 5.6 you can do this:

```
var activeArray: [Zot]
{
    _read { yield arrays[activeArrayIndex] }
    _modify { yield &arrays[activeArrayIndex] }
}
```

More details [here](https://trycombine.com/posts/swift-read-modify-coroutines/)

This is an experimental but I don't think it's likely to go away.

Comment: I knew the init was confusing as well, thank you for helping to simplify it. I was thinking I might take Joakim's advice and drop the activeArray property entirely, but actually, I think it's used often enough, your idea of using a get/set might be more efficient with what I'm working in.

This has been a huge help, thank you

Comment: @TinyTim just be aware that there might be array copying going on which will impact performance.

Comment: I think that's true, but the arrays themselves shouldn't ever grow very large, no more than 1-5 values in them